# wysihtml5 cursor jumps to wrong place on new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

When 'return' or 'enter' is hit, the cursor does not follow the actual line. Is there a solution to the problem? There are a few forks to the plugin which fixes the issue, but I am curious what the actual solution was to fix it.

This is a jQuery plugin based on the project: https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/ and you can see the error: http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/ (hit enter a few times)

Comment: what browser is this ?

Comment: @astro Chrome 39.0.2171.71

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been discussed [on the project's GitHub page](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/issues/497).

The fix is [mentioned in the above thread](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/issues/497#issuecomment-55598639):

```
// "commenting these lines (5869 and 5870) in wysihtml5-0.3.0.js fixes it:
// composer.commands.exec("insertLineBreak");
// event.preventDefault();"
// 
// Example:

if (keyCode === wysihtml5.ENTER_KEY && !wysihtml5.browser.insertsLineBreaksOnReturn())  {
    //composer.commands.exec("insertLineBreak");
    //event.preventDefault();
}
```